# Balanced sampling in R

Tags: r, sampling, large-data

Currently I'm using "cube" function for balanced sampling in R. It works fine on moderate amount of data. However, if the entire population of 10,000,000+ is used, R hangs. Is there any alternative that works with "big-data"?

Comment: Can you please supply [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should reinstall the package `BalancedSampling` to make sure that you have the latest version 1.4. For me, it seems to work fine for `N = 10000000` (takes about 30s to select a sample)

```
library(BalancedSampling)
N = 10000000 # population size
n = 100 # sample size
p = rep(n/N,N) # inclusion probabilities
X = cbind(p,runif(N),runif(N),runif(N)) # matrix of 3 auxiliary variables
system.time(cube(p,X))
 user  system elapsed
 31.31    0.02   31.42
```